# Is there a way to initialize an object through a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, constructor, initialization

If I have this class:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :b,:c,:d
end
```

and this code:

```
a = A.new
h = {"b"=>10,"c"=>20,"d"=>30}
```

is it possible to initialize the object directly from the hash, without me needing to go over each pair and call `instance_variable_set`? Something like:

```
a = A.new(h)
```

which should cause each instance variable to be initialized to the one that has the same name in the hash.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can define an initialize function on your class:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :b,:c,:d
  def initialize(h)
    h.each {|k,v| public_send("#{k}=",v)}
  end
end
```

Or you can create a module and then "mix it in"

```
module HashConstructed
 def initialize(h)
  h.each {|k,v| public_send("#{k}=",v)}
 end
end

class Foo
 include HashConstructed
 attr_accessor :foo, :bar
end
```

Alternatively you can try something like [constructor](http://atomicobjectrb.rubyforge.org/constructor/)

Comment: +1. BTW, you may want to consider using `public_send` instead of `send` to avoid calling private attribute writers :)

Answer (score 19):

`OpenStruct`is worth considering:

```
require 'ostruct' # stdlib, no download
the_hash = {"b"=>10, "c"=>20, "d"=>30}
there_you_go = OpenStruct.new(the_hash)
p there_you_go.c #=> 20
```

Comment: Yep! And you can also convert JSON to OpenStruct, which is nice. `JSON.parse({a: 1, b: 2}.to_json, object_class: OpenStruct)`

Answer (score 11):

`instance_variable_set` is intended for this kind of use case:

```
class A
  def initialize(h)
    h.each {|k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}",v)}
  end
end
```

It's a public method, so you could also call it after construction:

```
a = A.new({})
a.instance_variable_set(:@foo,1)
```

But note the implied warning in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set):

> Sets the instance variable names by symbol to object, thereby frustrating the efforts of the class’s author to attempt to provide proper encapsulation. The variable did not have to exist prior to this call.

Comment: To me, the checking to ensure you can only set those specified in the definition is quite important, which renders this suggestion unworthy